# Difference between three cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have three cells A,B and C (A=80 B=79.1 C=79.1).
I require cell D to display the 0.9 difference that occurs and if the case is none match

`If A=B=C = 0

If A=B<>C = difference between A and C

If A=C<>B = difference between A and B
`

Comment: What's your question?  You can use IF and - in excel.  Made easier by the last 2 outcomes doing the same operation.

Comment: Im not 100% sure how to write it !

Comment: `=IF(AND(A1=B1,A1=C1,B1=C1),0,IF(AND(A1=B1,B1<>C1),A1-C1,IF(AND(A1=C1,B1<>C1),A1-B1,IF(AND(B1=C1,A1<>C1),A1-B1,FALSE))))` - there's probably a better way to write it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I agree *very* similar to your other question, but rather than letter references I have taken the differences and wrapped them in [ABS](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/ABS-function-3420200f-5628-4e8c-99da-c99d7c87713c) as I can't see any sign convention making much sense:

```
=IF(AND(A1=B1,A1=C1),"match",IF(A1=B1,ABS(A1-C1),IF(A1=C1,ABS(B1-A1),IF(B1=C1,ABS(A1-B1),"none"))))
```